# Conflicting peer dependency: webpack@4.46.0 npm ERR! node_modules/webpack

Tags: javascript, npm, vuejs2, sass-loader

I cloned one repository from github then installed npm packages using npm install, but I get this error

[image]

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/composition-api": "^1.0.0-rc.6",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "less": "^4.1.1",
    "less-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.6",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
```

How can I get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found this issue from my project which I built last two weeks. Now, this month (May 2021) [sass-lang](https://sass-lang.com/) says ***LibSass and Node Sass are deprecated***

try this commands-

```
yarn remove node-sass
yarn add sass
```

or `npm` commands

Comment: This fixed everything, thanks!